# jquery cookie asp.net

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am trying to use jquery cookie plugin on my website. what am i doing is show firstdiv on page load wait for some time and remove the firstdiv and show the secdiv and again wait for sometime, then remove the secdiv and finally show the maindiv. This works fine but want this to happen only when you visit the home page first time but not also for every subsequent visits during that active session. trying jquery to fix this issue. here is what i have now and doesnt seem to work well. It just loads the maindiv on all the occasions. could you please put me in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var visitcookie = $.cookie('visitcookie', 'first', { Path: "/", expires: 0 });
       if (visitcookie == 'first') {
            document.getElementById('secdiv').style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById('maindiv').style.visibility = "hidden";
            setTimeout(function () {
            $("#firstdiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("#firstdiv").remove();
            document.getElementById('secdiv').style.visibility = "visible";
            $("#secdiv").show();
            $("#secdiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("#secdiv").remove();
            document.getElementById('maindiv').style.visibility = "visible";
            $("#maindiv").show();
            $.cookie('visitcookie', 'second');
                        });
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('secdiv').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('maindiv').style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });
```

Comment: i have noticed that cookie value is changed to 'second'.what could be the problem?

Comment: sorry! i have noticed that cookie value is not changed to 'second'.what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do an alert to visitcookie it returns:
visitcookie=first; expires=date...
so what I did is a substring 12 characters to remove the "visitcookie=" and then just return "first" hope this helps..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var visitcookie = $.cookie('visitcookie');
   switch(visitcookie)
   {
        case 'first':
        document.getElementById('secdiv').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('maindiv').style.display = 'none';
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#firstdiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("#firstdiv").remove();
                document.getElementById('secdiv').style.visibility = "visible";
                $("#secdiv").show();
                $("#secdiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("#secdiv").remove();
                    document.getElementById('maindiv').style.visibility = "visible";
                    $("#maindiv").show();
                    $.cookie('visitcookie', 'second', { expires: 7 , Path: "/"});
                    });
                });
            }, 2000);
        break;

        case null:
            document.getElementById('secdiv').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('maindiv').style.display = 'none';
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#firstdiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("#firstdiv").remove();
                    document.getElementById('secdiv').style.visibility = "visible";
                    $("#secdiv").show();
                    $("#secdiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $("#secdiv").remove();
                        document.getElementById('maindiv').style.visibility = "visible";
                        $("#maindiv").show();
                        $.cookie('visitcookie', 'second', { expires: 7 , Path: "/"});
                        });
                    });
                }, 2000);
            break;  
        default:
            document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('secdiv').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('maindiv').style.visibility = "visible";
        break;
   }

});
```

*edit on page load you capture the cookie value then I did a switch so if the value is null then it goes through the process of display what you need then it sets the cookie value to second..when you visit another page and comeback it shows just the main div..I also went ahead and changed the "expire" to 7 because at 0 you couldn't test this correctly.. hope that helps you

Comment: oh and the switch is optional i use switch more often de if/elses but you don't have :)

Comment: @Andres-thanks for your help. what i want to achieve is when the user visits the home page first time, i want to show firstdiv, then secdiv and finally remove both div's and show the maindiv. but when the user goes to some other parts of website and comes back again to the home page he should see the maindiv directly. will the above code help to achieve this? Please let me know.. thanks a lot!

Comment: there you go also the $.cookie('visitcookie'); returns just the value and not the whole string so no need for any substring action ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
document.getElementById('firstdiv').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('secdiv').style.display = 'none';
```