# How do I implement jQuery Sidebar and Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup a sidebar via the jQuery API. Now I noticed that when I refresh the page, the sidebar is going to close itself automatically.

I found a cookie thing on the internet but for some reason it does not work with my sidebar script.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sidebar_status = $.cookie("sidebar_status");

    if (sidebar_status == null) {
        $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('closed');
        $("#sidebar").hide();
    };

    if (sidebar_status == "closed") {
        $("a#ToggleSidebar").removeClass('open');
        $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('closed');
        $("#sidebar").css("display", "none");
    };

    if (sidebar_status == "open") {
        $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('open');
    };


    $("a#ToggleSidebar").click(function() {
        if ($("a#ToggleSidebar").attr("class") == 'open') {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('closed');
            $.cookie("sidebar_status", "closed", {
                path: '/',
                expires: 100
            });
            $("#sidebar").animate({
                width: 'hide',
                opacity: 'hide'
            }, 'slow');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('closed');
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $.cookie("sidebar_status", "open", {
                path: '/',
                expires: 100
            });
            $("#sidebar").animate({
                width: 'show',
                opacity: 'show'
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

There is something like a button `<a href="#"></a>` which should open a `<div></div>`. Now, I expect that when somebody visits the page the first time, that the `<div></div>` is closed. When the user clicks on the `<a href="#"></a>` it opens the `<div></div>` and saves a cookie. When the user should now refresh the page, the `<div></div>` should stay open until the user uses the `<a href="#"></a>` to close it again. That is what I can not get to work.

Comment: What isn't working? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Look at this answer though not a solution to your problem but a alternative implementation of the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/8462362/406659

Comment: @C.Felix, when a comment asks for clarification, you'd add that bit to your original post by editing it; most especially if you need to post more code.

Comment: @Sparky672, thanks for the advice! I will remember this for the next question I should have ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment from OP:**  *Now the Sidebar opens and a cookie is saved on the computer, when I however try to close the sidebar again, nothing happens*.

For jQuery 1.6 and up, this...

```
if ($("a#ToggleSidebar").attr("class") == 'open') {
```

should be this (replace `attr` with `prop`)...

```
if ($("a#ToggleSidebar").prop("class") == 'open') {
```

But this is best...

```
if ($("a#ToggleSidebar").hasClass("open")) {
```

---

This...

```
$(this).removeClass('open');
$(this).addClass('closed');
```

....can simply be written as this (it's called chaining)...

```
$(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
```

---

While we're at it...

This:

```
if (sidebar_status == null) {
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('closed');
    $("#sidebar").hide();
};

if (sidebar_status == "closed") {
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").removeClass('open');
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('closed');
    $("#sidebar").css("display", "none");
};

if (sidebar_status == "open") {
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('open');
};
```

...can be written like this....

```
if (sidebar_status == null) {
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('closed');
    $("#sidebar").hide();
} else if (sidebar_status == "closed") {
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
    $("#sidebar").hide();
} else if (sidebar_status == "open") {
    $("a#ToggleSidebar").addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
};
```

(jQuery `.hide()` [is equivalent to](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) jQuery `.css("display", "none");`)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was reading through the jQuery page as an email arrived telling me that there is a new answer :)

Answer (score 0):

check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067996/933552) it was the same situation with jquery cookie plugin and how to use it.  Hope it helps or atleast guides you in the right direction.

Comment: An SO answer simply linking to another SO answer is not ideal.  Answers should be fully self contained.

Comment: it was my own answer i made on another post regarding cookies..should i have just copied/paste my own answer?

Comment: Why not?  It's your answer after all.

Comment: @Andres, unfortunately this does not help me :( I found the issue about the cookie not being saved. I was missing a }); at the end. Now the Sidebar opens and a cookie is saved on the computer, when I however try to close the sidebar again, nothing happens :(

Comment: do you mean it doesn't close or doesnt save the action in your cookie?